# Difference in meaning between "booking is amended" and "booking has been amended"

Tags: meaning, differences, british-english, present-perfect, present-tense

What is the difference in meaning between "booking is amended" and "booking has been amended"?

Answer (score 1):

Booking is amended means that some attribute of the booking identifies the booking record as "amended" - say on a computer system.

Booking has been amended means that the process of setting that attribute has been carried out.

Answer (score 0):

Booking has been amended is the correct usage.
Someone will only inform you of the new status of the booking.
"Is amended" just sounds inappropriate.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe that you can actually say: "Booking is amend" - "is" + "-ed" doesn't really work together.

Booking has been amended is the only correct sentence here.